# Eclipse Plugin Development - Getting information from Team Provider

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I am very new to developing eclipse plugins.  The biggest hurdle I am facing right now is where/how to get at the data from various other plugins.  I am having a real hard time finding documentation for this.  For instance the Team Provider plugin....

1. How do I read the svn revision of a file?  Lets say I have an IResourceChangeListener and I want to keep track of the svn revision number of a file (if the user did an update for example).
2. If I want to ask svn if there are pending updates for a project, how do I talk to the eclipse team provider?

I am not sure where to start...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually discovered what I was looking for after many hours of searching.  Unfortunately since I have less than 100 rep.  I have been unable to post until now....

I am making a little progress on this.  I randomly stumbled upon this while pouring through eclipse source code.

The following code snippet monitors everything that goes on with regard to an svn enabled project.  If you save a file, to an update, revert etc.  Anything that touches the files or meta data of the files.  I just print out the file/direcory name and its revision number.

**Subversive version:**

```
final Subscriber subscriber = UpdateSubscriber.instance();
subscriber.addListener(new ISubscriberChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void subscriberResourceChanged(ISubscriberChangeEvent[] events) {
        for(ISubscriberChangeEvent event : events) {
            UpdateSyncInfo info = (UpdateSyncInfo) subscriber.getSyncInfo(event.getResource());

            System.out.println(event.getResource().getName()+" revision: "+uInfo.getLocalResource().getRevision());
        }
    }
});
```

The real trick was figuring out the entry point to get at this information:  UpdateSubscriber.  It would be nice if there was a good resource for finding out this sort of information.

**Subclipse version:**

```
private static final Subscriber subscriber = SVNWorkspaceSubscriber.getInstance();
private static final ISubscriberChangeListener subsciberListener = new ISubscriberChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void subscriberResourceChanged(ISubscriberChangeEvent[] events) {
        try {
            for (ISubscriberChangeEvent event : events) {
                SVNStatusSyncInfo info = (SVNStatusSyncInfo) subscriber.getSyncInfo(event.getResource());
                System.out.println(event.getResource().getName() + " revision: " + info.getRepositoryRevision());
            }
        } catch (TeamException e) {
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    super.start(context);

    subscriber.addListener(subsciberListener);
}

@Override
public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    subscriber.removeListener(subsciberListener);

    super.stop(context);
}
```

Comment: +1, you are a saint for returning with this piece of information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Added the subclipse equivalent for anyone who may benefit.

Answer (score 1):

For general information on the Team API in the Eclipse platform, review the documentation in the help system.

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/team.htm

(If you're working with the Subscriber stuff, it appears that's mentioned under the "Synchronization Support" -> "Beyond the Basics" topic.)

The Java doc for the **team** packages also helps:

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/team/core/package-summary.html

If you're trying to integrate with or otherwise extend the Subclipse or Subversive team providers, you may have better luck asking your question in their forums:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewForums.do

http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/newsgroup.php

Answer (score 0):

One starting point would be to [explore the sources](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/trunk/?root=Technology_SUBVERSIVE) of [subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) to see how they did their implementation of the features you are describing.

The sources for `eclipse.team` (the common module for all VCS plugins) [are available in a Git repo](http://dev.eclipse.org/git/index.html).

The [sources for EGit](https://github.com/eclipse/egit), another VCS plugin (for Git) can also be instructive.